# HQL 'with' clause in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

From Hibernate 3.6 documentation:

> You may supply extra join conditions using the HQL with keyword.

```
from Cat as cat
left join cat.kittens as kitten
    with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

This `with` clause allows to add a restriction on the JOIN condition (ON clause). Is there any such thing in JPQL?

When I run the following JPQL:

```
select c from ContainerDef c left join fetch c.displayState ds where c.id = 1 and ds.user.id = 2
```

The following SQL is generated:

```
select
        ...
    from
        CONTAINER_DEF containerd0_ 
    left outer join
        USER_CONTAINERDEF displaysta1_ 
            on containerd0_.CONTAINERDEF_ID=displaysta1_.CONTAINERDEF_ID 
    where
        containerd0_.CONTAINERDEF_ID=? 
        and displaysta1_.AUTHUSER_ID=?
```

What should really get generated is:

```
select
        ...
    from
        CONTAINER_DEF containerd0_ 
    left outer join
        USER_CONTAINERDEF displaysta1_ 
            on containerd0_.CONTAINERDEF_ID=displaysta1_.CONTAINERDEF_ID 
            and displaysta1_.AUTHUSER_ID=?
    where
        containerd0_.CONTAINERDEF_ID=?
```

I am sure I'm missing the right JPQL clause for HQL's `with`.

Comment: From Hibernate documentation: `HQL also defines a WITH clause to qualify the join conditions. Again, this is specific to HQL; JPQL does not define this feature.` http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2705

Comment: Note that in Hibernate you can use `with` in JPQL as well.

Comment: @axtavt I tried that, it threw IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such a feature in JPQL. Support for joining with specific condition is mentioned in [JPA 2.1 topic list](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338):

> -- support for outer joins with ON conditions;

So maybe JPQL will have it in future.

Answer (score 2):

But you can do it with Criteria API

```
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Cat.class);
    crit.createAlias("kittens", "kitten", 
        Criteria.LEFT_JOIN, Restrictions.gt("weight", 10.0);

    List<Cat> catsWithFatKittens = crit.list();
```

This is the barely documented signature of `Criteria.createAlias()` with a Restriction object as the fourth parameter. It works so well that it is worth learning Criteria API to get the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.1 added support for [ON join](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#ON_.28JPA_2.1.29) conditions.

It's also a better name choice than the HQL 'with' clause.